# How to set transition between day and night images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Setting smooth transition between day and night :

Javascript :

```
function dayAndNight(){
    if($('#achtergrond').attr('class')== "night")
            $('#achtergrond').toggleClass('night day');
    else if($('#achtergrond').attr('class')== "day")
            $('#achtergrond').toggleClass('day night');
}
```

How to set gentle transition between ,

Day & Night :

[image]

[image]

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/4csF3/17/)

Comment: I'd use something like [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)

Comment: Since @Legionar added the jqueryui tag, have you considered [using `switchClass`](http://api.jqueryui.com/switchClass/)?

Comment: here, question was closed before i could answer http://jsfiddle.net/4csF3/21/